# Is possible to use the default wpf designer for custom "controls" not inheriting from ContentControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to use the wpf editor for creating interfaces for an application that just accept a byte array (a bitmap). In this situation, I obviusly won't use any ContentControl, so I tried by inheriting DependencyObject, however I can't "render" anything in wpf editor. Are there any possibility to effectively render something that is not a ContentControl?

Even a workaround inheriting ContentControl (but when I instanciate) the class obviusly I should instanciate (in code) something different that doesn't create a real window.

Comment: No that I know of - I recommend using Expression Blend.  Its editor supports custom styles much better than VS2010.

Comment: That's not the point, what I want is SUPPORT visual editors, actually I can't show my controls because they aren't inheriting from Control class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched all over the web and I definitely think it's not possible except with great hacks where you force the editor to use a class different from what it uses in running mode.